# A proof about convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n)$, given $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

**Hypothesis**

1. $a_n > 0$, for all $n\ge 1$.
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

**Why I am asking**

I'm reading *Continued Fractions* by A. Ya. Khinchin. This statement helps to prove the convergence of an infinite continued fraction.

**Comments**

I actually found the same question searching here, and tried to understand them. But I don't understand the proofs given. An example I have seen is a proof by equivalence test. If it is possible, I need a more basic prove. Otherwise, any other is welcome :)
PD: Sorry for my english xd. I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Note that $\frac {x-1}{x}\le \log(x) \le x-1$ for $0<x<1$

Comment: Your main question is only in your title. It should also be in the body.

Comment: We may assume $a_n<1$ since it is the case for $n$ large enough. Then
$\prod (1-a_n)$ converges iff $\log\prod (1-a_n)$ converges iff $\sum \log(1-a_n)$ converges. Since $a_n\rightarrow 0$, $\log(1-a_n)\sim a_n$ and you're done !

Answer (score 0):

Convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies $a_n \rightarrow 0$. Then there is an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $a_n <1$.

If we put
$$
b_n = \prod_{i=N}^{N+n} \left( 1-a_i \right)
$$
then the sequence $\left\{b_n\right\}$ is decreasing (since $0<1-a_n<1$ for $n \geq N$) and bounded (since $0<b_n<1$ for all $n$).

Hence $b=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$ exists and is finite so that
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1-a_n \right) =
\left[\prod_{n=1}^{N-1} \left( 1-a_n \right)\right] \cdot
\left[\prod_{n=N}^\infty \left( 1-a_n \right)\right] =
\left[\prod_{n=1}^{N-1} \left( 1-a_n \right)\right] \cdot 
b
$$
and the result follows.